# Regex - find all optional group occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating regex in JavaScript that find all groups occurrences, all optional. I found many questions, but none of answers works for me.

I'm using `xregexp` package, but for simplicity I've create online demo.

Input:

```
new-rooms-3-area-50
new-foo-rooms-3-area-50-bar
new-qwe-more-rooms-3-asdads-anything-area-50-uiop
new-blah-more-area-50-else
```

Requested output:

```
["rooms-3", "area-50"]
["rooms-3", "area-50"]
["rooms-3", "area-50"]
["area-50"]
```

I have now

```
new-(rooms-\d+)?.*(area-\d+)
```

regex. Probably I shouldn't use `.*` set, but I don't know how can I *skip* some unneeded parts.

Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/QvmYN0/2/

You can fork and save fixed solution at `regex101` site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
new-(?:.*?(rooms-\d+))?.*?(area-\d+)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QvmYN0/4)

The point is to make the capturing group *obligatory* but put it into an optional non-capturing group. The last `*` greedy quantifier is converted to a lazy one, but it is not necessary.

**Details**:

- `new-` - matches an obligatory `new-`
- `(?:.*?(rooms-\d+))?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences, greedy match, i.e. the regex engine will try to match the pattern of the group) sequence of:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (that is,
    lazy matching, the pattern is skipped and the subsequent patterns are tried first,
    and is only expanded once the subsequent patterns fail)
  - `(rooms-\d+)`  - Group 1: `rooms-` and 1+ digits (now, it is not optional, must match or the whole non-capturing group will match an empty string)
- `.*?`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(area-\d+)` - Group 2: `area-`  and 1+ digits.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I've spent few hours today with this problem and I almost lost hope. Have a nice day.

Comment: Well, you do not need an XRegExp for this and you could split it into two separate regexps.

Comment: I know, but I create this code in react application. XRegExp is only for named groups.