# Regex - collect characters between obligatory prefix and optional groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating regex in JavaScript that find all groups occurrences, all optional.

I have collected optional groups (thanks for [@wiktor-stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786404/regex-find-all-optional-group-occurrences)) now. Missing thing is *gathering* characters between `new-` prefix and first occurred group.

Input:

```
new-rooms-3-area-50
new-poland-warsaw-rooms-3-area-50-bar
new-some-important-location-rooms-3-asdads-anything-area-50-uiop
new-another-location-area-50-else
```

Requested output:

```
["rooms-3", "area-50"]
["poland-warsaw", "rooms-3", "area-50"]
["some-important-location", "rooms-3", "area-50"]
["another-location", "area-50"]
```

I have now

```
new-(?:.*?(rooms-\d+))?.*?(area-\d+)
```

regex. I think that collecting `.*` between `new-` and `rooms|area` may be stupid solution.

Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/QvmYN0/5

*Note: I created two separated questions, because it refers to 2 separately problems. I hope that somebody have similar problems in the future.*

Comment: Can you explain the requested output? Why avoid `asdads-anything`? Why take `some-important-location`? What's wrong with `new`, `bar`, `uiop` and `else`?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Sure. I need to parse friendly URL (the input) to the parameters (the output). I don't have anything but input strings. Strings `asdads-anything`, `new`, `bar` etc should never appear in input, but I need to be sure.

Comment: This question is rather unclear. You may capture the `.*?` and check if Group 2 is matched. If Group 2 matched, use Group 1 as the new value, else use Group 3.

Comment: You have variable field info to collect. Unfortunately in JS can't accommodate that in it's regex. You could however, set a fixed amount of capture groups, let's say to 10 or so, which could split that up for you. Alternatively, you'd have to use some form of _split()_.

Comment: For a pure regex solution [`^new-(?:(.*?)-)?(?:(rooms-\d+).*?-)?(area-\d+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/QvmYN0/6) may work if you  can tolerate an empty string in output for couple of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to split by steps like this:

```js
// Split by \n to work with each line
getArrays = input => input.split`\n`.map(x => {

  // Split by your desired delimiters:
  // -dashes which has "area" or "rooms" in front
  return x.split(/-(?=area-|rooms-)/g).map(y => {

    // remove the "new-" from start or anything in front the numbers
    return y.replace(/^new-|\D+$/, '');

  // make sure you don't have empty cases
  }).filter(y => y);

});

var txt = `new-rooms-3-area-50
new-poland-warsaw-rooms-3-area-50-bar
new-some-important-location-rooms-3-asdads-anything-area-50-uiop
new-another-location-area-50-else`;

console.log(getArrays(txt));
```

**EDIT:**
The above code returns the requested output. However, I was thinking you should want an array of models instead:

```js
// initial state of your model
getModel = () => ({
  new: '',
  area: 0,
  rooms: 0,
});

// the function that will return the array of models:
getModels = input => input.split`\n`.map(line => {
  var model = getModel();
  
  // set delimiters:
  var delimiters = new RegExp(
    '-(?=(?:' + Object.keys(model).join`|` + ')-)', 'g');
  
  // set the properties of your model:
  line.split(delimiters).forEach(item => {
    
    // remove non-digits after the last digit:
    item.replace(/(\d)\D+$/, '$1')
    
      // set each matched property:
      .replace(/^([^-]+)-(.*)/, 
        (whole_match, key, val) => model[key] = val);
  });
  
  return model;
});

var txt = `new-rooms-3-area-50
new-poland-warsaw-rooms-3-area-50-bar
new-some-important-location-rooms-3-asdads-anything-area-50-uiop
new-another-location-area-50-else`;

console.log(getModels(txt));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the high-end solution which does it all at once.
Doesn't split or massage the data, just takes it as is (and always will be).
It may not be for beginners, but be for the more experienced.

(*Note that I don't know JS, but I can tell you, this took about 20 minutes

googling about strings. This is just too easy, do people really get paid

to do this ?!*)

This uses exec to push each element ( group 2 )
and create an array of records, one for each line.

```
    ( ^ new )                     # (1)
 |  
    (                             # (2 start)
         (?: rooms | area )
         - \d+ 
      |  (?:
              (?:
                   (?!
                        (?: rooms | area )
                        - \d+ 
                   )
                   [a-z] 
              )+
              (?:
                   -
                   (?:
                        (?!
                             (?: rooms | area )
                             - \d+ 
                        )
                        [a-z] 
                   )+
              )+
         )
    )                             # (2 end)
```

```js
var strTarget = "\
new-rooms-3-area-50\n\
new-poland-warsaw-rooms-3-area-50-bar\n\
new-some-important-location-rooms-3-asdads-anything-area-50-uiop\n\
new-another-location-area-50-else\n\
";

var RxLine = /^new.+/mg;
var RxRecord = /(^new)|((?:rooms|area)-\d+|(?:(?:(?!(?:rooms|area)-\d+)[a-z])+(?:-(?:(?!(?:rooms|area)-\d+)[a-z])+)+))/g;

var records = [];
var matches
var match;

while( (match = RxLine.exec( strTarget )) ){
    var line = match[0];
    matches = [];
    while( (match = RxRecord.exec( line )) ){
        if ( match[2] )
            matches.push( match[2] );
    }
    records.push( matches );
}
     
console.log( records );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
`new-(.*?)?-?(rooms-\d+|area-\d+).*?(area-\d+)?.*`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Qvdkdx/1